# VMWare: Check if 3D Hardware is used for rendering or not

Tags: graphics, vmware, opengl, mesa, gallium

How do I check whether my VMWare installation is using the GPU on the computer or using software rendering?

The output from glxinfo is

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.2.1
```